# Can anyone tell me why I got this error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I got this error when I clicked my login button, I was expecting the validator would work but I just got this error every time I clicked my login button

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:project_ukk/…/login/login_page.dart:153
#1      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:989
#2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:198
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:608
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:296
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:230
#6      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:563
#7      PointerRouter._dispatch
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94
#8      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139
#9      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137
#11     PointerRouter.route
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123
#12     GestureBinding.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:439
#13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:419
#14     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:322
#15     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:374
#16     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:338
#17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:296
#18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:279
#22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#23     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#db891
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(296.1, 619.7)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(266.1, 36.2)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
```

**This is my login_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/constants/color_constant.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/constants/font_and_padding.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/reset_password/reset_password.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/signUp/signup_page.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/user_page/navbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  //Form Key
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var email = "";
  var password = "";

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  clearText() {
    emailController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
  }

  userLogin() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PageNavBar(),
        ),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print("No User Found for that Email");
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            content: Text(
              "No User Found for that Email",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print("Wrong Password Provided by User");
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            content: Text(
              "Wrong Password Provided by User",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Email Field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: emailController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please Enter Email';
        } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
          return 'Please Enter Valid Email';
        }
        return null;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Email",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //Password Field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: passwordController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please Enter Password';
        }
        return null;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
    final loginButton = Material(
      elevation: 2,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: const [kDarkModerateCyan, kModerateCyan],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: MaterialButton(
              child: Text(
                "Login",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: textButton,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 15),
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, otherwise false.
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  setState(() {
                    email = emailController.text;
                    password = passwordController.text;
                  });
                  userLogin();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    final forgotPassword = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ResetPassword(),
            ),
          ),
        },
        child: Text(
          'Forgot Password ?',
          style: TextStyle(
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    final registerNow = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "Don't have an account? ",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          child: Text(
            "Register Now",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: kPrimaryColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SignUpPage(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      body: Stack(
        key: _formKey,
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kWhiteColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
                    ),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [kDarkModerateCyan, kModerateCyan],
                      stops: [0.0, 1],
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/logo.svg',
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          color: kWhiteColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 30,
                  ),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 70,
                      ),
                      emailField,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      passwordField,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      forgotPassword,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      loginButton,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      registerNow,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My code is not connected to Firebase yet because I want to test if my validator is working or not, but I got this error instead.

Comment: can you tell code line that causing the problem login_page.dart:153 i need to know code in this line

Comment: @ThalindaBandara it was this part if (_formKey.currentState!.validate())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the form key in `Stack` instead of a `Form`

To fix this, you can simply wrap your `Stack` with a `Form`, and move your key to that `Form`

like

```dart
...
return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
...
```

Apart from that, I'd suggest putting your UI elements(login, email, and forgotPassword) outside the `build` method, to achieve it you'll have to create methods for them instead of having a field/variable

Comment: Thank you, the solution is working fine and the message showed up as well

Comment: you're welcome @MonsterEat, happy to help :)